# WCF RIA Service with Unity 3.5.1.0

Tags: wcf, unity-container, wcf-ria-services, prism-4

I'm trying to Use this Blog for WCF RIA Applcation . So I Create a Silverlight Nevigation Applciation which gave me 2 projects abs & abs.Web

More I create 3 project in solution :

1. abs.Data (c#),  DbContext Implemeantion of Repository Interfaces +Factory to provide What user want.
2. abs.Data.Contarct  (c#) Interfaces for Operations Repository
3. abs.Data.Model  (c#) - Contains POCO - EF 6

Now I created A wcf Service in abs.Web project which have constructor injection of a Repository to get my job done in operation contracts.
So I tried using Unity here under the guidence with below blog

http://jamesheppinstall.wordpress.com/2012/06/20/windows-communication-foundation-resolving-wcf-service-dependencies-with-unity/

Now I'm getting

**The service type provided could not be loaded as a service because it does not have a default (parameter-less) constructor. To fix the problem, add a default constructor to the type, or pass an instance of the type to the host.**

**Description:** An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

**Exception Details:** System.InvalidOperationException: The service type provided could not be loaded as a service because it does not have a default (parameter-less) constructor. To fix the problem, add a default constructor to the type, or pass an instance of the type to the host.

**Source Error:**

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

**Stack Trace: **

[InvalidOperationException: The service type provided could not be loaded as a   service because it does not have a default (parameter-less) constructor. To fix the problem, add a default constructor to the type, or pass an instance of the type to the host.]

```
  System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.InstanceBehavior..ctor(DispatchRuntime dispatch, ImmutableDispatchRuntime immutableRuntime) +12761206
  System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime..ctor(DispatchRuntime dispatch) +173
 System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchRuntime.GetRuntimeCore() +85
 System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelDispatcher.OnOpened() +148
 System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout) +321
 System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout) +139
 System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout) +310
 System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open() +36
 System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.ActivateService(ServiceActivationInfo serviceActivationInfo, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity) +91
 System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity) +598

[ServiceActivationException: The service '/DomainServices/UserWcfService.svc' cannot be activated due to an exception during compilation.  The exception message is: The service type provided could not be loaded as a service because it does not have a default (parameter-less) constructor. To fix the problem, add a default constructor to the type, or pass an instance of the type to the host..]
 System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result) +499812
 System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result) +178
 System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHttpHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +6
 System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.OnAsyncHandlerCompletion(IAsyncResult ar) +129




 Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET      Version:4.0.30319.18446
```

My all classes are same as like Blog.

Answer (score 0):

WCF Ria has its own factory. 
Simply put

```
public class MyDomainServiceFactory : IDomainServiceFactory
{

    #region IDomainServiceFactory Members

    public DomainService CreateDomainService(Type domainServiceType, DomainServiceContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!typeof (DomainService).IsAssignableFrom(domainServiceType))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException(String.Format("Cannot create an instance of {0} since it does not inherit from DomainService", domainServiceType), "domainServiceType");
            }

            if (IoC.IsRegistered(domainServiceType))
            {

                var dmnService = (DomainService) IoC.Resolve(domainServiceType);
                dmnService.Initialize(context);
                return dmnService;
            }
            else
            {
                //if the IoC container doesn't know the service, simply try to call its default constructor
                //could throw proper exception as well
                var dmnService = (DomainService) Activator.CreateInstance(domainServiceType);
                dmnService.Initialize(context);
                return dmnService;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ExceptionHandler.HandleException(ex);
            return null;
        }

    }


    public void ReleaseDomainService(DomainService domainService)
    {
        domainService.Dispose();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

and somewhere on your bootstrapping code add

```
 DomainService.Factory = new MyDomainServiceFactory();
```

of course, the word *IoC* in the factory identify the unityContainer (is actually a static façade against it)